# Ubuntu Server to Chromecast

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, server, chromecast

I am running Ubuntu Server 15.04, I want to send a website page to a local Chromecast device to display on a television.

When on Windows, you can open chrome browser, navigate to the website page, and cast the tab. I wish to cast a website in this same manner as a background process from a Ubuntu Server - command line only.

How can this be done?